# Which pentacube oddities can be solved or improved?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, 3d, symmetry, polyomino

A few years ago I studied pentacube oddities.  A pentacube is a polycube with 5 cells, and an oddity is an arrangement of an odd number of copies of a polyform that has binary symmetry (or stronger).  So far as I know, Torsten Sillke was the first to study oddities in general, and polycube oddities in particular.  Mike Reid has also studied
them.

In particular, I wanted oddities with full (cubic) symmetry.  This page summarizes my results: [https://userpages.monmouth.com/~colonel/c5odd/index.html](https://userpages.monmouth.com/%7Ecolonel/c5odd/index.html).

This catalogue has weaknesses.  Among achiral (mirror-symmetric) pentacubes, my solutions for the T, W, and Z pentacubes are made from rectangular boxes known to be tilable.  They have hundreds or thousands of tiles.  I have no solution for the X pentacube.

Among chiral pentacubes, my solutions for the H and S pentacubes are formed from rectangular boxes.  They have 145 and 675 tiles respectively.  I have no solution for the G pentacube unless we let the tiles be reflected.

Can anyone improve on these results, or suggest a method for improving them?

Comment: I don't have any suggestions, but noticed you have a slight mistake on your page. In the Chiral, Disallowing Reflection section, the last 3d shape, the large cross with 145 piece, the bottom 4x5x5 arm is a mirror image of the top one. Easily fixed of course by reflecting it to match the rest.

Comment: Thank you for spotting this error!  I have redrawn the tiling so that all the tiles have the same chirality. (Use shift-reload to see the change.)